# Prove that the column space of $AC$ is contained in the column space of $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Prove that the column space of $AC$ is contained in the column space of $A$.

The only way I can think of is to write out column vectors of $AC$, and notice that the column vectors of $AC$ are linear combinations of column vectors of $A$. (Or, we don't even have to "write out" to notice that, by definition column vectors of $AC$ are indeed linear combinations of column vectors of $A$.) Therefore, the column space of $AC$ is contained in the column space of $A$.

First of all, is this proof correct?

Second, is there a better way to prove it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your idea for a proof is good. A second approach which may be faster is the following. The column space of matrix $A$ is:
\begin{align}
\text{Col}(A)=\{ b\in V | \exists x\in W: Ax=b\}
\end{align}
Where $V$ and $W$ are some vector spaces, for example $V=\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $b\in \text{Col}(AC)$ then there exists $x$ such that $ACx=b$. Take $y=Cx$ so there exists $y$ such that $Ay=b$ hence $b\in \text{Col}(A)$. And that means $\text{Col}(AC)\subset \text{Col}(A)$.

Answer (score 2):

It's a an absolutely correct answer.